# i want number of rows in android

Tags: android, cursor

I am using cursor.getcount but its not working i am confused. I am trying to get data from labels against given date but its not working.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            date=et.getText().toString();

            cursor= db.rawQuery("Select count(*) from labels where date='" + date + "'", null);
            //  db.openDatabase(path, factory, flags)
            //  Log.d("Query", "Select count(*) from labels where date='" + date + "'");


            //Log.d("cursor Length", )
            if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Download Latest Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: How have you defined cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query as

```
"Select count(*)AS count from labels where date='" + date + "'"
```

Replace this `if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0)` with

```
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("count"))>0)
```

Or in **other way** you can simply change your query as

```
"Select * from labels where date='" + date + "'"
```

and your other code will work as same as you have done.